# Fetch MSSQL database data online

Tags: php, android, sql

Well I am new in android development, and I want to create an android app that only fetch sales figures and some purchase reports from mssql database tables, that is online.
Is it possible?
And is it also possible to code in php?

Answer (score 2):

You can't/shouldn't access the LIVE db directly from your Android app. It is recommended that you build RESTFul web-services using PHP which will serve the required data to Android app in JSON format and you parse the JSON data to required objects and display/interact with that data on the Android app.

Comment: couldn't understand

Comment: @AhmadAfzaal , you need to write the business logic later which will serve the required data to Android app when web-service will be called from app. Are you aware of how web-services work?

Comment: @gurdeh singh yes i know that

Comment: @AhmadAfzaal then what exactly you need help on?

Comment: ok if i build web based is possible to fetch easy mssql data through apis from my home based server?